# How Can I change or style the Arrow inside the "rightcircle" Icon in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

How Can I change the Color or style the Arrow inside the "rightcircle" Icon in React Native?

the default Color of the Arrow is White

https://icons.expo.fyi/AntDesign/rightcircle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVG of that icon is the filled part, that means the arrow is not white, is actually transparent, so you need to wrap the icon on a sized view and change the background color:

```
<View style={{
    backgroundColor:"red",
    width:24,
    height:24,
    borderRadius:12
  }}>
    <AntDesign style={{
    }} name="rightcircle" size={24} color="black"/>
  </View>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank u  Karlo 